# Using aggregate methods( SUM as of here) in laravel query for complex queries

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have to run a query to find out the total orders for each quantity as

```
  SELECT userorders.`delivered` as delivered_status, items.`name` as itemname, 
sizes.`size` as sizename,SUM(userorders.`order_qty`) as order_quantity, 
sizes.`qty` as stockremaining FROM userorders inner join sizes on 
userorders.`size`=sizes.`id` inner join items on  sizes.`item_id`=items.`id`
 WHERE 1 group by userorders.`delivered`, userorders.`size`;
```

Roughly, its laravel equivalent is

```
 $userorders = DB::table('userorders')
            ->join('sizes', 'userorders.size', '=', 'sizes.id')
            ->join('items', 'sizes.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
            ->join('categories', 'items.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->select('SUM(userorders.order_qty) as order_quantity','userorders.delivered as delivered_status', 'items.name as itemname','categories.name as categoryname', 'sizes.size as sizename','sizes.qty as stockremaining')
            ->groupBy('userorders.delivered', 'userorders.size')
            ->get();
```

But, it seems laravel doesnt support aggregate parameters.
I found out that for getting just the aggregate quantity we could use it as

```
$userorders = DB::table('userorders')
                ->join('sizes', 'userorders.size', '=', 'sizes.id')
                ->join('items', 'sizes.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
                ->join('categories', 'items.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->SUM('userorders.order_qty');
```

But it seems not to be working in my case for getting the sum as well as other parameters too.
Could someone suggest me the way how to make it work??

Comment: As TB infers, your original query is suspect because it omits from the group by clause non-aggregated columns in the select clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DB::raw`:

```
$userorders = DB::table('userorders')
                ->select('userorders.delivered', 'userorders.size',
                          DB::raw('SUM(userorders.order_qty) as total_qty'))
                ->join('sizes', 'userorders.size', '=', 'sizes.id')
                ->join('items', 'sizes.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
                ->join('categories', 'items.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->groupBy('userorders.delivered', 'userorders.size');
```

Note carefully that I only select three things, the two columns which appear in the `GROUP BY` clause and the aggregate of the order quantity.  Selecting any other non aggregate columns would technically be an invalid query (though MySQL might tolerate it).

Comment: Thats it. Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, whatever advantage is afforded by not using raw, is then lost? Otherwise why not use raw for everything? (Perhaps you can tell that frameworks are a complete mystery to me)

Comment: @Strawberry This is actually the approach used in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-methods).  I'm not sure about the performance implication, but the bigger concern with raw fragments is SQL injection (which we don't want).

Answer (score 0):

To use aggregates with eloquent or the query builder you need to use `raw` methods. Roughly something like:

```
->selectRaw('SUM(userorders.order_qty) as order_quantity','userorders.delivered as delivered_status', 'items.name as itemname','categories.name as categoryname', 'sizes.size as sizename','sizes.qty as stockremaining')
```

See the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Thats it. Thanks.